# Skip files from tar if there is already tar-ed version?

Tags: command-line, tar

Does the `tar` command have an option to skip/ignore tar-ing the already tar-ed files?

consider I had a *`file1.txt`* and it's tar-ed as *`file1.tar.gz`* , now I copied another copy of *`file1.txt`* and a lot of other files like *`file2.txt`*, *`file3.txt`*, etc

what I expect, when tar-ing all these files, don't tar *`file1.txt`* again; I'm not interested in excluding all `*.tar.gz` files since it doesn't telling `tar` command to don't pick *`file1.txt`* to tar.

What I need actually prevent *`file1.txt`* to pick by `tar` command to do tar it as *`file1.tar.gz`* again which that's exist before (right now its overwriting).

**Note:** I could write a script, but I want to make sure, `tar` command cannot do this.

Comment: No, you will have to exclude them from the file list you feed to tar, f.e.: `tar cvf /storage/someFiles.tar $(find /sourceDir | grep -v '.tar')`. Not sure the syntax is correct, but I trust you get the idea.

Comment: The linux filesystem(s) doesn't have any notion of what you did to a file earlier, and how should the tar command know where to look for things you have tar'ed in an other session?

Comment: @SorenA it can be implemented as the same way as `mv  file1.txt file1.txt` does for example. so when you do something like `tar -czf file1.tar.gz file1.txt` and again and again trying to do the same `tar -czf file1.tar.gz file1.txt`, I wanted `tar` to knows that there is `file1.tar.gz` already why it bother itself to tar it again. idea is coming from where I wanted to tar a very big file and every time it will try to tar and tar and tar again --->

Comment: <---  (yes, I need to run it within find [as shown below answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145338/283843) in find command but without checking if there is its tar version and wanted tar manage it by itself for every files found ).

Comment: What ever `mv file1.txt file1.txt` does, it do it within it's own invocation / session. What you wan't to do with tar are over multiple invocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds `tar` currently has no possibility to skip files those that have a tar-ed version, so this is a way to skip those files:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    [ -f "${1%.txt}.tar.gz" ] && echo "$1 skipping ..." || echo "$1 taring ..."
' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can achieve that using the following tar command:

```
tar -cf koko.tar --exclude="*.tar" kokotar
```

Another neat trick is to create a file with the patterns of file names or extension you wish to ignore then read that file from the `tar` command to ignore all such file with this:

```
tar -cf koko.tar --exclude-from <file | /path/to/exclusion/list/file> kokotar

or

tar -cf koko.tar -X <file | /path/to/exclusion/list/file> kokotar
```

Syntax format:

```
tar -cf <name_of_new_tar_file>.tar --exclude='pattern' <source>

tar -cf <name_of_new_tar_file>.tar --exclude-from /path/to/name/exclusion/list <source>
```

Comment: sorry, but seems this only exclude *. tar files only to don't re-tar, not prevent kokotar to don't tar as kokotar.tar while there is kokotar.tar

Comment: Oh is that what you meant?

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't answer my question as I explained.